# How to hide the icon menu on large screens?

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm new at this and let me know how to hide the menu icon , and it adds automatically without being prompted, i want only to display on small screens. Sorry for the bad English.

Thank You.

Comment: no need to worry about the english. can you define large screen? Anyway, you can definitely detect screen size. For example, using jquery,$(window).height();   
$(document).height(); $(window).width();   
$(document).width();

Comment: sorry, the little code i added in the comments looks ugly. but anyway, refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window, to see how you can get the screen size then show / hide your menu accordingly

Comment: @dshun If the question is not tagged with jQuery or asking directly for jQuery it is best to not provide a jQuery solution. The solution is available directly from MDL without any extra stuff being pulled in.

Answer (score 5):

I had to resort to a Media Query to solve my problem.

`@media only screen and (min-width:851px){
    .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
        display: none;
    }
}`

It is the best solution I've found, thanks to @dshun and @garbee for help.

Comment: it hides the button but will leave unused space

Answer (score 3):

Another way of achieving this, is to add the various screen size classes, such as

```
mdl-layout--small-screen-only
```

. Here is an example:

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Drawer Title</span>

    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link 1</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link 2</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link 3</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My apologies if that snippet doesn't work well for you. I just noticed a similar question here on StackOverflow, the solution there may be more proper: [How can I hide drawer on large screens and show just on small screens.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495669/how-can-i-hide-drawer-on-large-screens-and-show-just-on-small-screens)

Comment: Can you please answer the question post in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754638/different-mdl-layout-drawer-for-large-screen-and-small-screen-in-mdl

Answer (score 3):

```
mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button
```

Does not display a drawer button in desktop mode, goes on `mdl-layout element`

Here is an example of the same:

`<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mdl-layout--fixed-drawer` on the same element you use `mdl-js-layout` to get a fixed drawer on desktop which should remove the button to view it and leave it open all the time for access.

Answer (score 0):

The effective solution I found and that finaly works is :

```
<style>
       @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
            /* Hide the Hamburger button but will leave an unused space */
            display: none;
        }
        .mdl-layout__header-row {
            /* so important to make sure the Hamburger button didn't leave an unused space */
            padding-left: 24px !important; 
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide div in large screen please add this class

```
hide-on-large-only
```