# How can I hide drawer on large screens and show just on small screens.?

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Even though I add "mdl-layout--small-screen-only" class on the drawer, the hamburger image still appears on large screens.

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

All I need is hiding drawer including the icon on navbar while on large screens. Thanks

Comment: Please show the CSS & media queries

Comment: I just tried your code ( adding 'mdl-layout--small-screen-only') because I'm having the same issue and it works fine.

Comment: @rsano is right. All you need to do is add "mdl-layout--small-screen-only"

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/layout/layout.js#L126

I made a jsfiddle so you can see it working.
https://jsfiddle.net/michaelguild/uj824wdv/17/embedded/result/

Answer (score 11):

`mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button`

Does not display a drawer button in desktop mode

Optional; goes on `mdl-layout` element

[GitHub](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/1467/files)

Comment: That's cool! Is there also somethong like `mdl-layout--no-tablet-drawer-button`?

Comment: Seems like there is no such an option, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your css. This hides on the screens less than 1024px width

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .mdl-layout__drawer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

P.S. Have no idea what is `.mdl-layout--small-screen-only` looks like some BEMish framework/library for something. Probably media queries are not in the correct order or you have some faily setup or whatever. I'm not a telepath. Have never been though I tried. Possly things change in some future (distant or near).

Comment: `.mdl-layout--small-screen-only` "Hides an element on larger screens", It's in the [layout documentation](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/src/layout)

Answer (score 0):

try the class

```
hide-on-large-only
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the

```
mdl-layout--small-screen-only
```

With a

```
mdl-cell--hide-desktop
```

Presto.

See here: http://mdlhut.com/2015/07/mdl-displaying-content-for-specific-viewports/

Comment: mdl needs to iron out their responsive/media query classes.

After looking at the js, it looks like "mdl-layout--small-screen-only" is exactly what it's looking for.

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/layout/layout.js#L126

Comment: mdl-cell--hide-desktop is for use with divs using the mdl-cell class.